# Как вынести определённый механизм в отдельный класс и затем обращаться к нему и правильно ли это с точки зрения ООП

Tags: c#, ооп, классы

Как вынести определённый механизм в отдельный класс и затем обращаться к нему и правильно ли это с точки зрения ООП.
есть код:

```js
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
 
namespace InstaBulochka
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
 
        IWebDriver web;
        public Form1()
        {
          
            
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArguments("--headless"); //
            web = new ChromeDriver(@"D:/");
            web.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
 
            InitializeComponent();
 
 
        }
 
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
          
            
            web.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.123.com/accounts/login/");
            web.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name='username']")).SendKeys("login");
            web.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name='password']")).SendKeys("passport");
            web.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name='password']")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
            try { String err = web.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#slfErrorAlert")).Text;
                Console.WriteLine(err);
            } catch (Exception ) { Console.WriteLine("log and pass is good"); }
 
        
 
            Console.WriteLine(isSMSOnPagePresent("Подозрительная попытка входа"));
 
 
        }
 
        public Boolean isSMSOnPagePresent(String text) {
            IWebElement body = web.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
            String bodyText = body.Text;
            return bodyText.Contains(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Хотелось бы, весь процесс авторизации вынести в отдельный класс ну скажем avtoriz (мне кажется так удобнее) и обращаться к нему из главного класса Form1. Как-то так, абстрактно: avtoriz.авторизироваться(лог,пасс); при этом конструктор IWebDriver web; должен быть именно только в классе Form1, и не создавая новых экземпляров объекта.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение желательно кодом. 
И с точки зрения ООП правильно ли я хочу сделать?

Comment: ну а какие у вас проблемы с этим? Какие то конкретные вопросы интересуют? Вы сами то покажите что пытались

Comment: тот код, который в евенте кнопки сделать отдельным классом. Проблема в том, что вызвать экземпляр конструктора IWebDriver web; необходимо только в основном классе... я не понимаю как этот экземпляр наследовать в другом классе не вызывая его заново. Это нужно для того, что бы не открывать ещё одно лишнее окно браузера. Если говорить глобальнее и проще, вот что я хочу: открыть единожды браузер IWebDriver web; и работать во всех классах только с ним, не создавая новых окон браузера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

делаем класс для аутентификатора

```
public class Authenticator
{
    private IWebDriver _driver;
    public Authenticator(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        _driver = driver;
    }

    public void Authenticate(string login, string password)
    {
         _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.123.com/accounts/login/");
        ..........
    }
}
```

Правим код формы

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    private Authenticator _authenticator;
    IWebDriver web;

    public MyForm()
    {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArguments("--headless"); //
        web = new ChromeDriver(@"D:/");
        web.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);


        _authenticator = new Authenticator(web);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _authenticator.Authenticate("login", "password");
    }
}
```

всё.

**upd**

Как я пришел к такому решению? 
Изначально автор просил выделить конкретный функционал в отдельный класс. Так родился класс

```
public class Authenticator
{       
    public void Authenticate(string login, string password)
    {
        web.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.123.com/accounts/login/");
        ..........
    }
}
```

однако, у класса пока нет одного параметра - `web`, который пока не настроен и непонятно как с ним работать. Для его передачи в класс есть 2 опции: передать его в конструктор, или передать её прямо в метод вместе с другими параметрами метода. 
Поскольку параметр `web` не специфичен для конкретного запроса, а, скорее, лежит в основе класса `Authenticator` (то есть если, например, вы добавите в класс метод `LogOff`, то вам параметры `login\password` уже не понадобятся - они нужны только для метода `Authenticate`, а вот `web` - понадобится, то есть он нужен не для одного метода, а для работы всего класса), я решил данный параметр рассматривать как зависимость класса и пробросил его через конструктор. Заодно и переименовал, мне удобнее его понимать как `driver` или `webdriver`, чем просто `web`. Подчеркивание перед названием поля - это просто следование общей рекомендации, когда имена всех приватных полей начинаются с подчеркивания. Подробнее про всякие рекомендации можно почитать [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/) или в [книге](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5588868/).

```
public class Authenticator
{
    private IWebDriver _driver;
    public Authenticator(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        _driver = driver;
    }

    public void Authenticate(string login, string password)
    {
        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.123.com/accounts/login/");
        ..........
    }
}
```

Далее, надо встроить этот класс в форму. Есть 2 варианта как это сделать. Первый - это создавать класс в обработчике события

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    IWebDriver web;
    ..........  
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var authenticator = new Authenticator(web);
        authenticator.Authenticate("login", "password");
    }
}
```

Это вроде кажется правильным подходом, но на самом деле, это нарушит принцип [единственности ответственности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) - ([подробнее про SOLID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))), так как мы не хотим, чтобы обработчики событий делали что то кроме обработки событий (то есть инициализация каких то сервисных классов не должна присутствовать в обработчиках, если вы не хотите в итоге получить лапшу в коде).

Остается инициализировать класс до того, как он понадобится. В идеале, мы знаем, что класс `Authentocator` - это зависимость формы и должен быть передан в конструктор формы (см материал про [Dependency Injection](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/905310/179763)), но я решил, что у вас нет ни корня агрегации, ничего, с чем можно работать прямо "по правилам", потому я показал более легкий вариант - с созданием зависимости прямо в конструкторе класса. Это не очень хорошая практика в больших корпоративных решениях, но в каких-то небольших проектах такое вполне допустимо, если без фанатизма.

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    private Authenticator _authenticator;
    IWebDriver web;

    public MyForm()
    {
        .......
        web = new ChromeDriver(@"D:/");
        ........    
        _authenticator = new Authenticator(web);
    }   
    ..........
}
```

Так и получился тот ответ, что я вам привёл.

Comment: Большое спасибо, работает, а можно разъяснить вкратце "на пальцах" основные моменты про взаимодействие классов в вашем решении. И ещё вопрос, что означает нижнее подчеркивание в имени _authenticator?

Comment: @АндрейИванов обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

например так:

```
public static class WebDriverExt
{
    public static bool LogIn(this IWebDriver driver, string login, string path)
    {
        driver.GoToUrl("https://www.123.com/accounts/login/");
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name='username']")).SendKeys("login");
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name='password']")).SendKeys("passport");
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name='password']")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
        //...
    }

    public static bool GoToUrl(this IWebDriver driver, string url)
    {
        // todo: проверка url
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
    }
}
```

использовать так:

```
driver.LogIn("login", "pass");
```