# Какие подходы для работы со сложными формами работают?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования

### Исходные данные:

- Имеется настольное приложение. Для простоты будем считать, что приложение содержит только одну форму.
- Функционал приложения: скачать по сети некоторую модель, натянуть эту модель на форму, пользователь эту модель редактирует, по окончании измененная модель едет дальше по сети
- Технологии: WPF, MVVM

### Особенности приложения:

Отличительная черта приложения состоит в том, что эта форма содержит очень много полей, очень много логики, очень много связей между полями. Грубо говоря, 90% кода - это логика и обслуживание полей на форме.

### Архитектура:

Как я уже упомянул, используется MVVM паттерн как основа архитектуры. Модель, грубо говоря, здесь выражена как чисто POCO объект - сущность, которая предназначена для сериализации/десериализации при общении с сервером + её можно собрать из классов ViewModel

### История:

Изначально всё было просто - одна модель, одна вьюмодель, одна вьюха

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, требования всё отгружали и отгружали, когда количество полей перевалило за 50, пришлось делить главную вьюмодель, модель и представление на части, но это всё по прежнему собиралось в одну форму. Главная вьюмодель осталась, но, чтобы уменьшить сложность, из неё были вынесены все неосновные поля, эти поля были сгруппированы в более мелкие вьюмодели и код был организован так, что мелкие вьюмодели знали о главной и главная знала о мелких.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Форма стала выглядеть как то так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код выглядел как то так:

```
public class MainViewModel 
{
    public Field1 Field1{get;set;}
    public Field2 Field2{get;set;}

    public ViewModel1 ViewModel1{get;set;}  
    public ViewModel2 ViewModel2{get;set;}  
    public ViewModel3 ViewModel3{get;set;}  
}


public class ViewModel1
{
    public Field3 Field3{get;set;}

    public ViewModel1(MainViewModel main)
    {       
    }
}

public class ViewModel2
{
    public Field4 Field4{get;set;}

    public ViewModel2(MainViewModel main)
    {
    }
}

public class ViewModel3
{
    public Field5 Field5{get;set;}

    public ViewModel3(MainViewModel main)
    {
    }
}
```

Но дальше - больше. Если количество полей растет линейно, то количество логических взаимосвязей между полями - растет гораздо быстрей. Очень быстро появились кросс-секционные поля, которые нельзя строго отнести к какой то секции, так как они состоят в логической зависимости от полей из нескольких секций сразу. Конечно, верным решением было бы вынести вообще взаимодействие полей в модель, но этого не было сделано, а вместо этого логика продолжала существовать во вьюмоделях. Таким образом, потребовался механизм взаимодействия полей между вьюмоделями, который был решен с помощью локальной шины. Всё стало ещё интересней

```
public class ViewModel1
{
    public Field3 Field3
    {
        get => _field3 
        set 
        {
            var oldValue = _field3; 
            if (SetProperty(ref _field3, value))
            LocalBus.Raise(new Field3Cahnged(oldValue, value))
        }   
    }

    public ViewModel1(MainViewModel main)
    {       
    }
}

public class ViewModel2
{
    public Field4 Field4{get;set;}

    public ViewModel2(MainViewModel main)
    {
        LocalBus.Subscribe<Field3Cahnged>(ev => {.. logic ..});
    }
}
```

### Проблемы

Как несложно догадаться, спустя всего несколько лет эксплуатирования подобной схемы, бизнес-логика стала просто мешаниной событий, валидация стала ночным кошмаром, отладка событий в многопоточном окружении растягивается при любом расследовании логики работы приложения. Основное, что могу выделить

- Код больше не отражает бизнес-процессы. Установка значения для поля может обернуться 10 последовательными событиями. Или параллельными.
- race condition встречается очень часто
- тестируемость решения низкая. Чтобы написать тест логики на изменение поля, надо нагородить вьюмоделей и постоянно проверять что проехало по шине + какие изменения произошли в моделях. Так как всё взаимосвязано, то зачастую приходится поднимать все вьюмодели для теста одного изменения. Как итог, тесты либо отсутствуют, либо быстро устаревают. Количество дефектов растет.
- Расследование дефектов занимает много времени
- Внесение изменений занимает много времени

Для упрощения, я не стал расписывать другие аспекты формы, например

- Баннеры, алерты, всплывающие сообщения
- асинхронная работа (поля активно работают с сетью)
- наборы секций и полей на экране сильно зависят от модели. То есть модели с разными данными, грубо говоря, обращаются в разные комбинации вьюмоделей и по разному представлены на форме
- Фоновые бизнес процессы могут в любой момент вмешаться в работу формы
- Какие-либо другие сюрпризы, хранящиеся в исходном коде, наподобии самописных AOP, пулах всего подряд и проч.

### Вопрос

Я постарался расписать подход работы со сложными формами, который был реализован в работающем приложении. Я не могу сказать, что он совсем нерабочий - нет, он дает некоторое разделение кода, и до определенного момента работает.

Однако, текущая архитектура нуждается если не в полной переработке, то точно в серьезном рефакторинге в целях:

- повышения качества продукта, его тестируемости
- уменьшения количества дефектов
- уменьшения времени добавления новых фич

Как бы я видел идеальную архитектуру, она должна позволять следующее:

- код полностью отражает бизнес процессы. Если в коде есть метод `SetModelQuantity(...)` - то содержимое метода ясно расскажет, что происходит при этом изменении
- Код легко тестировать. Должна быть возможность для юнит тестирования любой новой функциональности
- Вероятно, логика модели должна быть отделена от логики вьюмоделей. При этом встаёт вопрос - а как будут общаться модели разных секций?

Поэтому вопросы звучат так:

- какой подход к организации кода/архитектуры вы бы могли посоветовать?
- Какие примеры архитектур, решающие схожую задачу существуют?
- Какие этапы рефакторинга вы бы могли посоветовать? И как при этом не упасть в качестве, учитывая примерно 50% покрытие тестами (остальные 50% как то работают, но никто не знает как)?
- Любые ссылки или литература приветствуются

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Как-то мне приходилось писать формы по 70 - 90 полей с логикой (оттуда я вынес, что форма должна быть на 5-7 полей, не больше - иначе что-то [бизнес перемудрил](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN3qR.jpg)); поэтому с удовольствием почитаю советы. Меня вот интересуют подробности по форме: приходилось ли лезть в базу за данными для логики или достаточно было оперировать тем, что вводится?

Comment: @AK согласен с картинкой, но это реалии, на которые я не могу повлиять. По поводу формы - тут есть всё, кроме прямого доступа в БД. Поля могут отправлять запросы по сети и реагировать на ответы, некоторые ответы влияют на наборы полей, которые в свою очередь тоже могут отправлять запросы по сети и т.д. Есть подсказки, баннеры, попапы, модальные окна, которые оперируют с сетью. Это одна из причин почему тестирование стало болью - для теста надо поднимать чуть ли не все вьюмодели и мокать очень большое количество сервисов.

Comment: Это в главной форме такая беда?

Comment: @Vasek для упрощения считаем что в приложении только одна форма, и в ней такая беда

Comment: Как я понимаю, вопрос по сути сводится к тому как архитектурно работать с взаимодействием между многими модулями (конкретно: "есть что-то лучше, чем локальная шина для этого") но не абстрактно "по Фаулеру и ООПшным заветам" - а в приложении к конкретной области "формы MVVM". Я так вижу, что тут не просто дело в знании паттернов, тут нужны коллеги с подобным багажом в формах, которые уже пробовали все эти приёмы применять и набили шишек, знают какими тропами лучше ходить.

Comment: @AK да, я прошу поделиться конкретным опытом или хотя бы направить куда копать с пониманием профита от копания куда то. Знаний паттернов, ООП и заветов Фаулера у меня самого с избытком :)

Comment: Если взглянуть на схему из этого [видео](https://youtu.be/Zygw4UAxCdg?t=97), то вам, похоже, нужен слой `Application`, туда нужно начать перемещать логику "...логических взаимосвязей между полями..." и соответственно легче будет писать тесты.

Comment: @Bulson Я то видео не просто смотрел до дыр, но и применял [некоторые](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/968627/#comment1624320_968727) идеи в проектах. Оно хорошее, но как мне кажется к этому вопросу оно относится мало, потому что: а) mvc не mvvm б) вопрос больше не об общих принципах и ООПшных заветах, а о [практике](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/968627/#comment1624378_968627) применения. Ну то есть мало сказать "куда" перемещать, надо понимать "как".

Comment: @AK на мой взгляд эта "луковая" архитектура прекрасно будет работать и в случае MVVM - это же слой `Presentation`, а для того, чтоб упростить вьюмодели, нужно перенести часть логики куда? Вот как раз создать слой `Application` и вынести некоторые части туда.

Comment: @tym32167 Не очень хочу постить ответом, поэтому скажу так. Мне кажется, что текущий ваш подход при всех его недостатках - это лучшее, что только можно предложить. Или более мягко: на текущий момент в индустрии де-факто ваш подход является господствующим. Возьмите например vue.js: в нём для построения обмена данными между компонентами используется общая шина событий ([Event Bus](https://habr.com/ru/post/332628/)) на базе vuex. У вас кстати нет опыта работы с  redux/vuex? Возможно, какие-то идеи для проекта можно было бы заимствовать из этих фреймворков.

Comment: @Bulson спасибо за видео. Я пока немного приболел, как голова прояснится, я обязательно погляжу.

Comment: @AK спасибо. [Event Aggregator](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html) - это известный паттерн, потому его [суют](https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/event-aggregator.html) везде, где только можно. Я то не против паттерна, но вот сейчас хапнул проблем со слишком его повсеместным использованием, так как он не только разделил какие то части моего приложения, но и раздробил каждый бизнес-сценарий на много кусочков, и теперь не понятно, что из себя бизнес сценарии вообще представляет, код стал мешаниной

Comment: @AK в отличие от нашего подхода, тот же redux сам Ден Абрамов рекомендует использовать только если надо шарить какое то состояние с другими компонентами, а если речь о форме идет, то вроде он топил за то, чтобы данные формы оставались на форме. Если говорить про какой нить [redux-form](https://redux-form.com/), но там хранение состояния в глобальном хранилище как раз является минусом решения. Я это знаю, так как описываемый здесь код пытался портировать на react+redux, но мне пока не дали карт бланш

Comment: @tym32167 желаю скорейшего выздоровления :)

Comment: @Bulson спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Боюсь показаться банальным, но принципы SOLID пока еще никто не отменял:

1. Классы вью моделей не должны зависеть от других вью моделей напрямую, только от абстракций (интерфейсов). Уменьшение прямых зависимостей заметно облегчит юнит тестирование.
2. Ответственность вью модели - контролировать состояние вьюхи на основе модели и выступать между ними посредником. Не пытайтесь уместить всю бизнес логику во вью модель, этим должны заниматься сервисы.
3. Шина (медиатор) во многом является анти-паттерном, так как делает зависимости между компонентами неочевидными. Иногда это бывает полезно, но, скорее всего, не в вашем случае. Советую рассмотреть вариант коммуникации через модель/сервисы (когда вью модели подписываются на изменение состояния модели). Шине можно оставить нейтральные нотификации, от которых не зависит поведение конкретной вью модели (например "значения свойства изменилось", но при этом вью модели безразлично кто и как среагирует на эту нотификацию).
4. Избежать проблем с многопоточностью (в частости race condition) можно с помощью очереди background операций, с возможностью их отмены в любой момент (т.е. некое подобие Dispatcher-а).

Comment: 1) Каким именно образом добавление 600 интерфейсов мне облегчит тестирование? Каждая мини вьюмодель у меня знает только о родительской вьюмодели, таким образом прямая зависимость уже минимальна.

Comment: 2) Можете показать масштабируемый пример? Как сервисы будут общаться друг с другом? Кто их будет вызывать? Как сервисы будут взаимодействовать с вьюмоделью и моделью? Как при этом не получить мешанину сервисов? (учитывайте, что вьюмодель, как и модель, разбита на множество классов)

Comment: 3) Сейчас у меня есть шина и примерно 200 (может и больше) разных классов - событий. Вы предлагаете выпилить 200 классов и добавить 200 событий в модель? Я не очень понимаю, как это поможет?

Comment: 4) Да, кастомные очереди операций, свой тред пул и прочие вещи - это то, что уже есть. Race condition, как пример, возникает тогда, когда, например, одна модель создает event, у него есть 10 подписчиков, 5 из них делают что то асинхронное, а значит не блокируют вызывающий поток, а значит когда один подписчик доходит до асинхронного вызова, то возвращает управление и начинает работать другой подписчик, хотя первый ещё не закончил и ждет. В итоге получаем параллельную работу 2 подписчиков в одном потоке до асинхронной операции и в разных потоках после. Как это исправит пул задач?

Comment: 1) Ознакомьтесь с принципами ISP и DIP. Интерфейсы мокаются.
2) Если у сервиса миллион зависимостей, то нужно дробить сервис и эти зависимости уменьшать.
3) Модель на 200 событий? Дробите модель.
4) Не пул, а очередь.

Comment: 1) допустим, [ознакомился](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/905310/179763). Итак, у меня есть вьюмодель, для её создания мне нужна основная модель и шина. И у меня есть сценарии, по которому при изменении поля в этой вьюмодели, 5 других полей в других вьюмоделях, должны поменяться. Как выдление интерфейсов мне поможет?

Comment: 2) Это очевидно, как это применять в моем случае?  3) Уже раздроблена. Ну добавлю я по 10 событий в каждый кусочек, чем это поможет? 4) Что это меняет?

Comment: 1) Вам не нужна основная модель, вам нужны её конкретные методы/св-ва, которые зачем-то вызываются из дочерней вью модели. Эти зависимости нужно выделять в интерфейс (и задуматься, а так ли они нужны). Шина, скорее всего, тоже не нужна. Вью модель меняет состояние модели через сервис, заинтересованные вью модели меняют свое состояние. 2) Это поможет тем, что если у класса всего одна ответственность и минимум зависимостей, его проще поддерживать и тестировать. 4) В очереди не может быть race condition по определению.

Comment: 1) То есть вьюмодель отправляет запросы в сервис, сервис производит изменение модели, модель (или сервис) оповещает заинтересованные вьюмодели об изменениях через события? Я думал о таком решении, я вижу тут только одно преимущество - что вся бизнес логика по идее будет собрана в сервисах. Но это только до тех пор, пока кто то из девелоперов, не додумается вызвать сервисы внутри обработчика на изменение модели. После этого бизнес логика будет ещё более размазана. На самом деле я такую архитектуру уже видел, у неё есть свои особенности (как и плюсы, так и минусы, возможно опишу это отдельно)

Comment: 2) У меня нет проблем с тестированием одного поля. У меня проблемы с тестированием бизнес кейсов, когда вовлечены несколько классов

Comment: 4) Я понял про очередь, я не понял, как это поможет в моем конкретном сценарии

Answer (score 3):

Неоднократно приходится сталкиваться с подобными проблемами, поэтому выскажу свои мысли по этому вопросу:

Запутывание начинается с момента когда дочерняя VM начинает знать о родительской VM.

Бизнес-логика должна быть в модели. Если это правило не соблюдается, то она размазывается по вью-моделям, что приводит к двусторонней связи между дочерней и родительской VM.

```
public class MainViewModel 
{
    public Field1 Field1 { get; set;}        
    public ViewModel1 ViewModel1 { get; set;}

    ModelModel mainModel;
}

public class ViewModel1
{
    public Field3 Field3{get;set;}

    public ViewModel1(MainViewModel mainVM)
    { 

    }
}
```

в дочернюю VM необходимо передавать либо часть главной модели, либо всю модель сразу(как в вашем случае). Оттого и ViewModel и переводится как "представление модели" потому что она представляет модель, а не вью-модель не правда ли?)

```
public class ViewModel1
{
    public Field3 Field3{get;set;}

    public ViewModel1(MainModel model)
    { 

    }
}
```

"двустороннюю" связь можно реализовать через события модели. Главная/дочерняя вью-модель подписываются на нужные события модели и реагируют на изменения.

```
public class ViewModel1
{
    public Field3 Field3{get;set;}

    public ViewModel1(MainModel model)
    { 
        model.SomePropertyChanged += modelSomePropertyChanged; 
    }

    void modelSomePropertyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //что-то делаем...
    }
}
```

> Вероятно, логика модели должна быть отделена от логики вьюмоделей. При этом встаёт вопрос - а как будут общаться модели разных секций?

Разные секции получились в результате дробления главной модели и они должны быть между собой связаны? Вероятно лучше оставить одну большую модель, нежели раздробить ее на мелкие. Тот случай когда дробление больше  усложняет чем упрощает.

Comment: у меня секций примерно штук 15-20, полей всего очень много, больше сотни точно. Вьюмоделей, что содержат логику (и поля и секции) где то в районе 600 - как вы представляете модель таких размеров? Как вы представляете общение 600 вьюмоделей через события модели? В идеале, я бы вообще выпилил события, так как у меня уже глаз дергается, когда я вижу подписку на событие ради передачи сообщения.

Comment: @tym32167, вы что на одно поле отдельную VM заводите?

Comment: такое случается, если поле сложное и обладает своей логикой. Самый очевидный пример - поле-выпадающий список, который фильтруется в зависимости от других полей (данные для элементов качает по сети) и при выборе значения, проверяет некоторые условия (включая сетевой запрос) и в результате может отобразить предупреждение или какую то другую информацию касаемо выбранного значения.

Comment: @tym32167 Не думали ли о том, чтобы некоторые секции сделать отдельным контролом/компонентом - не для дальнейшего переиспользования даже, а скорее в целях изоляции определённой части доменной области? Вот именно на самом очевидном примере с адресом: в адресе может быть вшита разная логика для разных стран (условно: заполнять ли поле province), либо по известным 6 символам индекса предлагать адреса к автозаполнению.

Comment: @AK оно так и есть. Если вы поглядите на схему, то увидите, что есть конкретные представления, они привязаны 1 к 1 к конкретной маленькой вьюмодели, которая содержит в себе частичку модели. Единственное, что отделяет это от самостоятельного элемента - это ссылка на главную вьюмодель.

Comment: @AK даже более того скажу, поля, представленные вьюмоделями, тоже сделаны как отдельные контролы. То есть в итоге у меня композиция контролов и вьюмоделей, и их так много и связей между ними так много, что возникла проблема с отслеживанием логики, как и что работает.

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 1.** Бывает, что трудность реализации вызвана проблемой X/Y. Заказчик, имея проблему X, но не обладая техническими знаниями, предполагает, что эта проблема решается способом Y и просит сделать Y. Программист делает Y, но этот способ сложный, плохо ложится на парадигму реляционных данных, или объектов, или другую известную парадигму. Оказывается, что если попросить программиста решить задачу X, он предложит другое решение, гораздо более простое.

Типичный пример: медленные запросы к базе. Если спросить человека, который просит отчёт на 30 страниц, что он с ним будет делать, окажется, что он планирует просматривать его глазами в поисках каких-то важных данных. Но с этой работой гораздо лучше справляется компьютер, и для этого нужен другой запрос, гораздо более простой и производительный.

Поэтому первая рекомендация: ещё раз рассмотреть сценарии использования. Возможно, вместо одного сложного приложения лучше написать три простых для трёх разных ролей.

**Вариант 2.** Циклы в зависимостях возникают при попытке «формализовать неформализуемое». Предположим, есть поле A, от которого зависит поле B, а от того, в свою очередь — поле C. Построим направленный граф, и, если он ациклический, то формально мы можем построить модель и протестировать её. Но если вдруг поле A зависит от C, граф циклический, и у нас проблема. Уточню, что ациклический граф, это не всегда дерево, в нём ветки могут и сходиться, но они не образуют циклов.

Один из способов решения этой проблемы предложил Купер в своей книге «Психбольница в руках пациентов». Вы не пересчитываете C при изменении A, а проверяете попадание в диапазон. Если не попали, показываете это пользователю, но не запрещаете дальнейшее редактирование. Похожим образом действует проверка правописания: вы видите те слова, которые не известны программе, но сами решаете, ошибается программа, или нет. Если программа ошибается, вы просто игнорируете то, что подчёркнуто красной чертой. Но опечатку вы не пропустите.

**Вариант 3.** Подходящий инструмент. Бывает и так, что правила вполне можно формализовать, но сам язык не очень подходит для решения этой задачи. Часто нужно что-то вроде Пролога. Решением здесь являются кодогенерация и предметно-ориентированные языки (domain specific languages, DSL), которые можно использовать и в паре.

Например, вы можете описать бизнес-правила на языке собственной разработки, и при сборке проекта компилировать его в основной язык проекта. В современных ОО-языках наподобие C++, Java, C# хорошим решением является так называемая *текучая нотация* (fluent syntax), когда цепочка методов записывается через точку.

Скажем, в Entity Framework такой своеобразный DSL используется для описания отображений из БД в объекты:

```cs
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<OperationData> builder)
{
    builder.HasOne(x => x.Order)
           .WithMany(x => x.Operations)
           .HasForeignKey(x => x.OrderId)
           .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
}
```

Здесь с помощью цепочки методов строится модель, которая может быть даже формально проверена специально написанным методом.

Эта тема подробно освещена Фаулером сотоварищи в [книге о предметно-ориентированных языках](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/6967089/).

Comment: это всё хорошо, но я, если честно, слабо понимаю, как это всё относится к вопросу. 1) X/Y может и имеет место, но проблема в том, что приложение живет уже очень долго, 50% его функционала не описано даже в тестах, набора юзер-сценариев нет, времени на их составление нет, домен очень специфичный и сложный (есть специальные люди, которые в нем разбираются, и они перегружены работой), каждую фичу планируюут отдельные люди, решение о способе имплементации какой либо фичи принимают несколько команд вместе. Сесть, собрать юзер стори, переосмыслить и всё переделать нет ни времени, ни возможности

Comment: 2) Циклы случались, но их выявляли на тестах и правили. Проблемы решения циклических зависимостей нет, с этим справляемся

Comment: 3) DSL нет возможности использовать и не ясно как он поможет. Fluent - стиль хорошо, но тоже не очень понятно, как его наличие в коде что то упростит.

Comment: Для Fluent-нотации можно использовать [этот пакет](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation), но я тоже считаю, что ваш ответ несильно относится к заданному @tym32167 вопросу. Ну вот первая часть разве, но про достаточно было посетовать в комментариях на то, что бизнес иногда зря делает такие сложные формы (что я и сделал). Тут чисто архитектурный вопрос, как декомпозировать такие громоздкие и сложные штуки на простые в поддержке.