# Правильное использование DI и IoC

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, solid, inversion-of-control, autofac

Начал изучать принципы DI и работу с IoC контейнерами. Вопрос следующего характера:
Пусть у меня есть некая библиотека классов MyClassLibrary, там представлены следующие классы:

```
public class DefaultDownloader : IDownloader
{
    public string DownloadSomething(string param)
    {
        return $"{nameof(DefaultDownloader)} {param}";
    }
}

public static class MyContainer
{
    public static IContainer Container { get; set; }

    static MyContainer()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<DefaultDownloader>().As<IDownloader>();
        builder.RegisterType<FirstSource>().AsSelf();
        builder.RegisterType<SecondSource>().AsSelf();
        Container = builder.Build();
    }

}

public class SourceControl
{
    public string GetAllInfo(string param)
    {
        string toReturn = "";
        using (var scope = MyContainer.Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var source1 = scope.Resolve<FirstSource>();
            var source2 = scope.Resolve<SecondSource>();
            toReturn += source1.DownloadInformation("FirstSource");
            toReturn += " "+ source2.DownloadInformation("SecondSource");
        }

        return toReturn;
    }
}

public class FirstSource
{
    private readonly IDownloader downloader;

    public FirstSource(IDownloader downloader)
    {
        this.downloader = downloader;
    }

    public string DownloadInformation(string param)
    {
        return downloader.DownloadSomething(param);
    }
}

public class SecondSource
{
    private readonly IDownloader downloader;

    public SecondSource(IDownloader downloader)
    {
        this.downloader = downloader;
    }

    public string DownloadInformation(string param)
    {
        return downloader.DownloadSomething(param);
    }
}

public interface IDownloader
{
    string DownloadSomething(string param);
}
```

Этими классами можно пользоваться и по отдельности, но есть еще один класс (SourceControl), который позволяет забирать информацию со всех источников. В классе необходимо создать экземпляры источников (FirstSource, SecondSource) и вызвать некоторые методы оттуда. Соответственно, в этом же классе придется внедрять зависимости в FirstSource и SecondSource.

Использование извне:

```
class Program
{
    private static IContainer Container { get; set; }

    public static void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<MySecondDownloader>().As<IDownloader>();
        builder.RegisterType<FirstSource>().AsSelf();
        builder.RegisterType<SecondSource>().AsSelf();
        Container = builder.Build();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Следующие две строчки можно закомментировать, чтобы использовать
        // "стандартный" контейнер
        ConfigureContainer();
        MyContainer.Container = Container;

        SourceControl sourceControl = new SourceControl();
        Console.WriteLine(sourceControl.GetAllInfo("Main"));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class MyFirstDownloader : IDownloader
{
    public string DownloadSomething(string param)
    {
        return $"{nameof(MyFirstDownloader)} {param} - MODIFIED! (1)";
    }
}

public class MySecondDownloader : IDownloader
{
    public string DownloadSomething(string param)
    {
        return $"{nameof(MySecondDownloader)} {param} - MODIFIED! (2)";
    }
}
```

**Вопрос: Как это более правильно сделать с точки зрения логики и DI. В качестве IoC контейнера планирую использовать autofac. И правильно ли я сейчас это делаю?**

Comment: 1) выделяете интерфейс для источников 2) регистрируете их под этим интерфейсом 3) В новом классе получаете все зарегистрированные реализации интерфейса источника. Все

Comment: [не дубль, но может вам будет полезно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/905310/179763)

Comment: @tym32167 А если эти два класса реализуют обобщенный интерфейс `IGetMaxInfo<T>`?

Comment: ну пусть реализуют, какие проблемы с этим?

Comment: @tym32167 Честно говоря, немного не понял первый комментарий. Можете, пожалуйста, чуть-чуть по-подробнее объяснить, если не сложно, конечно?

Comment: давайте так: вы пишете ваш класс `но есть еще один класс, который позволяет забирать информацию со всех источников`, запускаете его, и если с ним возникают проблемы - обновляете вопрос и тогда будем смотреть. Пока что я проблемы в вашем вопросе не вижу.

Comment: @tym32167 Я правильно понимаю, что Resolve логику я должен буду поместить в этот класс, который занимается созданием экземпляров FirstSource и SecondSource. Как мне правильно сделать в этом классе ссылку на мой container, и где его правильней было объявить для последующего использования?

Comment: @tym32167 Я написал свою реализацию и поместил в вопрос, т.е. скорректировал его. Я правильно делаю или нет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш подход вызывает вопросы, например, зачем нужны разные классы для Downloader'ов, зачем разные источники, почему это нельзя просто сконфигурировать как надо и прочее.

Но давайте отойдем от этих вопросов и попробуем поработать с вашим кодом как есть.

Что мы имеем: 3 имплементации одного и того же интерфкейа, а значит, чтобы их различать, можно их регистрировать с [конкретными именами](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html).

Далее, источники должны быть ассоциированы только с соответствующими реализациями Downloader'ов.

И наконец, `SourceControl` должен быть также зарегистрирован и создан с помощью контейнера.

Ну и последнее, все эти именованные регистрации и сопоставления интерфейсов с реализацией должны находиться только на этапе конфигурации контейнера, то есть это должно быть абсолютно прозрачно для классов.

Со всеми этими требованиями, давайте сначала перепишем класс `SourceControl`

```
public class SourceControl
{
    private ILifetimeScope  _scopeFactory;

    public SourceControl(ILifetimeScope  scopeFactory)
    {       
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;       
    }

    public string GetAllInfo(string param)
    {
        string toReturn = "";
        using (var scope = _scopeFactory.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var source1 = scope.Resolve<FirstSource>();
            var source2 = scope.Resolve<SecondSource>();
            toReturn += source1.DownloadInformation("FirstSource");
            toReturn += "\n" + source2.DownloadInformation("SecondSource");
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

Создание контейнера становится таким

```
private static IContainer ConfigureContainer()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterType<MyFirstDownloader>().Named<IDownloader>("MyFirstDownloader");
    builder.RegisterType<MySecondDownloader>().Named<IDownloader>("MySecondDownloader");
    builder.RegisterType<DefaultDownloader>().Named<IDownloader>("DefaultDownloader");

    builder
        .RegisterType<FirstSource>()
        .WithParameter(
            new ResolvedParameter(
                (p, c) => p.ParameterType == typeof(IDownloader),
                (p, c) => c.ResolveNamed<IDownloader>("MyFirstDownloader")));

    builder
        .RegisterType<SecondSource>()
        .WithParameter(
            new ResolvedParameter(
                (p, c) => p.ParameterType == typeof(IDownloader),
                (p, c) => c.ResolveNamed<IDownloader>("MySecondDownloader")));  

    builder
        .RegisterType<SourceControl>(); 

    var container = builder.Build();
    return container;
}
```

Использование элементарное

```
var container = ConfigureContainer();
var control = container.Resolve<SourceControl>();    
Console.WriteLine(control.GetAllInfo("Main"));
```

Вывод

```
MyFirstDownloader FirstSource - MODIFIED! (1)
MySecondDownloader SecondSource - MODIFIED! (2)
```

Очень рекомендую к прочтению книгу Марка Симана - [Внедрение зависимостей в .NET](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/22104901/), многие вещи после этого станут на свои места.

**UPD**

Что тут ещё можно сделать. Если заметить, то источники по сути одинаковые, так что можно выделить интерфейс

```
public interface ISource
{   
    string DownloadInformation(string param);
}
```

Зарегистрировать источники как интерфейсы

```
private static IContainer ConfigureContainer()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterType<MyFirstDownloader>().Named<IDownloader>("MyFirstDownloader");
    builder.RegisterType<MySecondDownloader>().Named<IDownloader>("MySecondDownloader");
    builder.RegisterType<DefaultDownloader>().Named<IDownloader>("DefaultDownloader");

    builder
        .RegisterType<FirstSource>()
        .As<ISource>()
        .WithParameter(
            new ResolvedParameter(
                (p, c) => p.ParameterType == typeof(IDownloader),
                (p, c) => c.ResolveNamed<IDownloader>("MyFirstDownloader")));

    builder
        .RegisterType<SecondSource>()
        .As<ISource>()
        .WithParameter(
            new ResolvedParameter(
                (p, c) => p.ParameterType == typeof(IDownloader),
                (p, c) => c.ResolveNamed<IDownloader>("MySecondDownloader")));


    builder
        .RegisterType<SourceControl>();


    var container = builder.Build();
    return container;
}
```

И получать после просто их список

```
public class SourceControl
{
    private ILifetimeScope  _scopeFactory;

    public SourceControl(ILifetimeScope  scopeFactory)
    {       
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;       
    }

    public string GetAllInfo(string param)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (var scope = _scopeFactory.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var sources = scope.Resolve<IEnumerable<ISource>>();                
            foreach(var source in sources) 
                sb.AppendLine(source.DownloadInformation(source.GetType().Name));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Вывод будет аналогичный, но `SourceControl` теперь не знает ни о каких реализациях вообще.

**UPD 2**

Переписал `SourceControl`

```
public class SourceControl
{
    private IEnumerable<ISource> _sources;

    public SourceControl(IEnumerable<ISource> sources)
    {
        _sources = sources;
    }

    public string GetAllInfo(string param)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var source in _sources)
            sb.AppendLine(source.DownloadInformation(source.GetType().Name));
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за подробнейший ответ! Я правильно понимаю, что при использовании данных классов (которые являются классами в библиотеке) извне, например, при тестировании, я могу подменять контейнер на тестовый контейнер, верно?

Comment: @PracticeMakesPerfect фишка в том, что сами классы, по идее, не в курсе настроек контейнера или даже его наличия, потому вы можете в тестах конфигурировать контейнер по другому или даже обойтись без него.

Comment: Да, я понял, но SourceControl ведь знает, он создает экземпляры через scope Resolve?

Comment: @PracticeMakesPerfect `SourceControl` знает, что есть какой то интерфейс и что через него он может запросить реализации `ISource`, но вы можете сами реализовать `ILifetimeScope` и передать его в конструктор `SourceControl` без участия контейнеров. Кстати, мне также непонятно, зачем вам тут вообще нужен `ILifetimeScope`? Почему бы просто в конструкторе `SourceControl` сразу не принимать `IEnumerable<ISource>`? Типа `public SourceControl(IEnumerable<ISource> sources){....}`

Comment: Понял, спасибо! Про то, зачем нужен ILifetimeScope я понял из Вашего примера, ведь это Вы его туда поместили!

Comment: я кго туда поместил, так как вы использовали `using (var scope = _scopeFactory.BeginLifetimeScope())` в вашем коде.

Comment: добавил в ответ другую версию `SourceControl` без каких либо `Resolve`, возможно она вам тоже подойдет.

Comment: Спасибо большое!