# Property Injection с помощью Ninject

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ninject, di

Использую библиотеку Ninject.
Помогите разобраться почему не работает Property Injection.
В проекте создаю библиотеку классов и консольное приложение для ее отладки.
Добавляю UnitOfWork

```
internal interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    void SaveChanges();
    IRepository<T> Repository<T>() where T : class;
}

internal class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    [Inject]
    public IDBContext context { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            context.Dispose();
            context = null;
        }
    }

    public IRepository<T> Repository<T>() where T : class
    {
        return new Repository<T>();
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Также в библиотеке классов создаю модельный объект на основе данных из БД

```
internal class ObjCtlg
{
    public IEnumerable<IComposite> Items { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    internal IUnitOfWork uow { get; set; }

    public ObjCtlg()
    {
        using (uow)
        {
            Items = uow.Objects().Find(d => d.Id != 0).Select(c =>
            new Document
            {
                Id = c.Id,
                Name = c.Name,
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Добавляю модуль Ninject в библиотеку классов

```
public class NinjectBindingModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();
    }
}
```

В консольном приложении добавляю ядро Ninject

```
public static class IoCKernel
{
    private static IKernel kernel;

    public static void CreateKernel()
    {
        kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectSettings
        {
            InjectNonPublic = true,
            InjectParentPrivateProperties = true,
            LoadExtensions = true,
        });
        kernel.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
    }

    public static T Get<T>()
    {
        return kernel.Get<T>();
    }

    public static void Inject<T>(T item)
    {
        kernel.Inject(item);
    }
}
```

Создаю ядро при старте приложения

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IoCKernel.CreateKernel();
        var test = new Test();
    }
```

При создании ядра я прохожу по модулю "NinjectBindingModule : NinjectModule" из библиотеки классов. Т.е как я ожидаю Binding выполнился. После этого я создаю тестовый объект чтобы посмотреть как прошел биндинг UnitOfWork

```
internal class Test
{
    public ProgramFirst()
    {
        var t = new ObjCtlg();
    }
}
```

В итоге свойтсво имеет значение null

```
    [Inject]
    internal IUnitOfWork uow { get; set; }
```

Я ожидал что при создании тестового объекта произойдет Injection, но этого не происходит.
Новичек в Ninject подскажите что делаю не так?

Comment: Не знаю как работает ninject под капотом, но врядли он умеет магически определять когда надо заинжектить свойство. Нужно резолвить инстанс из контейнера, нет?)

Comment: @SultanovShamil У меня доступ к контейнеру есть из консольного приложения, а инжектирование происходит в библиотеке классов, из нее я не могу получить доступ к контейнеру. Ну я посмотрел здесь https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Injection-Patterns как выглядит инжектирование свойства и повторил, за исключением у них нет конструктора, а у меня есть. Ну как я ожидал инжектирование должно было (без магии;) произойти в момент обращения к свойству благодаря атрибуту [Inject]. Но видимо это не так

Comment: Атрибут только говорит, что когда вы будете создавать `ObjCtlg` используя контейнер, то контейнер просканирует свойства объекта и сделает Inject там, где есть этот атрибут. Но вы создаете объект сами, следовательно контейнер тут вообще не при делах и ничего никуда не инжектится.

Comment: @tym32167 Я ожидал что контейнер как вы и говорите просканирует свойства и найдет помеченое атрибутом, получит его тип в моем случае IUnitOfWork найдет по нему связку из модуля Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>(); и создаст его экземпляр. Но раз это не так, то каким образом мне самому создавать объект и где?

Comment: Вы сами уже пытались создавать руками, это не так работает. Возможно, у вас есть некоторые трудности с пониманием [Dependency Injection](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/905310/179763), или вам также неплохо бы почитать [документацию](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Dependency-Injection-With-Ninject) библиотеки. что вы собрались использовать.