# Помогите понять dependency injection

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

**Без Spring'a**

Есть обычный класс `GoogdClient` который реализует интерфейс `ClientRepo`

```
public class GoogdClient implements ClientRepo {
}
```

У класса есть метод, который был имплементирован из интерфейса. Он ищет по номеру Whatsapp, а если находит - возвращает клиента. Этот метод  называется `findByWhatsapp()`

Чтобы внедрить этот метод в контроллер без Spring мне бы пришлось бы в контроллере создать Объект `GoogdClient goodClient = new`  и вызвать у новосозданного объекта goodClient метод `findByWhatsapp()` Так?

**Что делает Spring**

Я просто в контроллер внедряю (injection)
`@Autiwired` интерфейс, класс `GoogdClient` я вообще не создаю
Spring мне из этого внедрения создаёт класс (Какой класс? Какой у него тип?)
Потом создаёт объект этого класса, у которого я и вызываю метод `findByWhatsapp()`

Так?

Comment: `Класса GoogdClient в Spring у меня вообще не существует.` - как объявлен интерфейс `ClientRepo` (в частности наследуется ли он от какого-то интерфейса и есть ли на нем аннотации)? Вы вероятно используете spring-data (прямо или через spring-boot) и вопрос об этом, т.е. о реализации репозитория которую использует spring?

Comment: Для общего понимания, не применительно к spring, есть вот такой [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/905310/179763)

Answer (score 1):

Все что вам нужно, чтобы внедрить зависимость в контроллер без спринга, это создать метод, который возвращает экземпляр класса

```
public class Spring {  
   public static ClientRepo getClientRepo() {
      return new GoogdClient();
   }
}
```

Поскольку Spring возвращает интерфейс, то можно не думая о том как имплементирован метод  `getClientRepo()` использовать

```
Spring.getClientRepo();
```

который и вернёт экземпляр `GoodClient`.

Спринг делает почти тоже самое, только используя `@Configuration`:

```
@Configuration
public class Spring {  
   @Bean
   public ClientRepo getClientRepo() {
      return new GoogdClient();
   }
}
```

после этого на все переменные с типом `ClientRepo` можно ставить `@Autowired`.

Comment: Если вам понравился ответ, или вы хотите принять его за правильный потому, что он вам помог решить проблему, то пометьте его галочкой напротив ответа. См. [Что означает если ответ "принят"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Spring сканирует классы и ищет подходящий для инъекции, в данном случае он находит класс GoogdClient, которые имплементирует ClientRepo и понимает, что он подходит. ClientRepo же помечен у вас как бин? Попробуйте создать другую имплементацию интерфейса ClientRepo и посмотрите, что произойдет при старте приложения

Comment: Нет. Класса GoogdClient в Spring у меня вообще не существует. Он есть в проекте без спринга. А имплементиркю я вообще интерфейс, что для меня дико, так как меня учили что НЕЛЬЗЯ создать объект интерфейса