# Как контроллер может использовать интерфейс?

Tags: python, интерфейс

Читаю книгу "Чистая Архитектура" и наткнулся на следующую схему:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заинтересовал кусок выше синей линии.

Цитата из книги: *"Контроллер упаковывает данные в простой Java-объект **InputData** и передает его через интерфейс **InputBoundary** классу **UseCaseInteractor**."*

Вопрос следующий:

- Как контроллер может использовать Интерфейс и "передавать данные", если у последнего все методы абстрактные и экземпляры абстрактного класса нельзя создавать?
- Можно ли сделать такое с помощью языка Python?
- Не могли бы вы привести небольшой пример такой конструкции или дать ссылки на материалы?

Не нашёл ответа на вопрос на схожих ответах на SO. В сети также распространены статьи и прочие материалы с базовой информацией на тему того, что такое интерфейс, но на такой "странный" вопрос нет ответа

Comment: Контроллер - это класс, который управляет вводом-выводом. В реализациях [Spring и Struts](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818691/204920) используется MVC паттерн, во его и надо читать. То, что касается диаграммы, то тут надо понимать [что такое внедрение зависимостей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1320038/204920), ну и по читать про SOLID принципы в программировании. На вопрос ответ дать нельзя, поскольку он не соответствует нормам принятым на этом сайте. См. [Как задавать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @RomanC Я правильно понял, что в данном случае Контроллер может использовать InputData и InputBoundary по принципу DI?

Comment: Да, правильно, только цитата из книги неправильна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тоже читал эту книгу когда-то. Не претендую на идеальный ответ, но по крайней мере хочется поделиться своим видением.

> Как контроллер может использовать Интерфейс и "передавать данные", если у последнего все методы абстрактные и экземпляры абстрактного класса нельзя создавать?

Интерфейс по умолчанию абстрактный потому что интерфейсы не стабильная часть системы (Сегодня мы работаем в консольном приложении, завтра выходит десктопная. При этом их функционал идентичен)

> Можно ли сделать такое с помощью языка Python?

Безусловно

> Не могли бы вы привести небольшой пример такой конструкции или дать ссылки на материалы?

Держи:

Допустим есть такая сущность

```py
class User:
    def __init__(self, name: str, surname: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
```

У нас есть контроллер который отвечает который передает данные, в виде экземпляров каких-то классов предоставляющих какую-то структуру данных

```py
class Controller:
    @classmethod
    def pack(name: str, surname: str):
        return User(name, surname)
```

Не стал далеко ходить и сделал интерфейс который преобразовывает данные в нужный вид (В нашем случае просто словарь)

```py
class AbstractInterface(ABC): 
    """
    тот самый абстрактный интерфейс, 
    который нужен потому что интерфейсов 
    может быть много а их методы сильно похожи
    """
    @abstractclassmethod
    def out():
        raise NotImplementedError

class ConsoleInterface(AbstractInterface): # класс наследник абстрактного интерфейса
    @classmethod
    def out(user: User):
        return {'name': user.name, 'surname': user.surname}
```

Есть вот такой вот вариант использования. Который предоставляет некий функционал

```py
class UserActions:
    def __init__(self, user: dict) -> None:
        self.user = user
    def say(self, text):
        print(f"{self.user['name']} says: {text}")
```

Реализация всего этого выглядит так:

```py
data = Controller.pack('John', 'Snow')
data_dict = ConsoleInterface.out(data)
john_actions = UserActions(data_dict)
john_actions.say("Hello")
```

Надеюсь я правильно понял твой вопрос

Comment: Большое спасибо. Очень помогло