# Asp.net mvc core приложение. Правильность архитектуры и чистый код

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, архитектура, best-practice, чистый-код

Я сделал свой первый pet-project и у меня возникло несколько вопросов в верности выбора архитектурного решения и best practice. (https://github.com/azaza12345/CsharpDapperExample)

1. Верна ли в принципе построенная мною архитектура? Контроллеры прокидывают информацию в сервисный слой, а те, в свою очередь работают с базой данных через репозитории?
2. Стоит ли нагромождать условиями и проверками service слой? Например, присваивать значение в конструкторе так: `_productRepository = productRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();`? Или проверять на null входящий в метод параметр?
3. Подсмотрел в других проектах использование интерфейса, например, `IProductService` для `ProductService` и не совсем разобрался для чего это нужно. По сути же этот интерфейс жёстко привязан именно к этому сервису не предполагает других его реализаций..? в чём я не прав? нормальной ли практикой будет просто регистрировать службу `ProductService` без интерфейса?
4. Следует ли разбивать класс миграций на несколько или можно создавать все нужные таблицы в одном?
5. Также буду рад любым найденным замечаниям и неточностям в моём проекте на основе best practice (это касается как целой архитектуры приложения, так и различных именований переменных/методов, clean code)

Comment: вы бы хоть картинку нарисовали какую, или вы предлагаете понять вашу архитектуру по вашему коду?

Comment: Какие метрики вы используете, чтобы понять качество вашего приложения? Количество классов? Строк на класс\метод? Покрытие тестами? Производительность?

Comment: @tym32167 ...Поддерживаемость? Модульность? Актуальность? Документированность? Технологичность?

Comment: @aepot что из этого можно измерить и как?

Comment: @tym32167 это скорее всего юмор был. Но качество кода от этого всего однозначно зависит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы хотели разбора вашего проекта, так что считайте сами напросились :)

1. Начем с названия. Название вашего проекта показывает язык/библиотеки, а не его назначение. Вы вот в "WPF_C#_C++" программе его писали или в "IDE Visual Studio"? Я, как человек, что делает ревью вашего приложения, первым делом вижу его название и оно ни о чем вообще не говорит. Называйте проект по его назначению, технологии перечислите уже в readme если в этои есть надобность. (см [Naming Guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines))
2. У вас часть контроллеров возвращает модели, а часть - view models - вы уже определитесь, есть у вас слой VM или нет.
3. Смотрю на котроллеры и не понимаю, вы как то заботитесь о HTTP кодах, что возвращаете? Почему для каких то методов вы используете `ValidateAntiForgeryToken`, а для каких то нет?
4. Ваши сервисы возвращают view models, вы точно знаете назначение сервисов? Почему сервисы знают о том, как информация будет отображаться? (см [PoEAA](https://martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html))
5. У вас авторизация включена, но я не вижу, где вы её используете?
6. Я так понимаю, вы полностью отказались от логгирования? Вам интересно, что с вашим приложением делают юзеры? Как вы узнаете о деталях проблемы, если она возникнет?
7. `SessionExtensions.GetItemsListFromSession<ShoppingCart>(_httpContextAccessor, WebConstants.SessionCart)` - вы знаете, как пользоваться extension методами?
8. Вы храните корзину в сессии для неавторизованного юзера, к чему вы будете заказ привязывать? Попросите юзера авторизоваться?
9. Почему у вас HomeService отвечает за операции с корзиной? У вас же есть CartService? В чем вообще назначение HomeService? Зачем он нужен? Сервисы создаются для доменных объектов, а не для страничек в интерфейсе.
10. С одной стороны у вас многослойная архитектура, а с другой стороны - вы позволяете себе вот это `var count = SessionExtensions.GetItemsListFromSession<ShoppingCart>(_httpContextAccessor, WebConstants.SessionCart).Count;` прямо в коде view. Будьте консистентны.
11. Убирайте закомментированные участки кода. Если вы не закончили задачу, держите её в другой ветке git
12. Тесты. `UnitTestsApp` как название проекта с тестами. Та же самая претензия как 1.
13. Открываю `CartServiceTest.cs` и не понимаю, что он тестирует.
14. `Assert.Equal(GetProducts().ElementAt(i).Name, result.ElementAt(i).Name);` используйте методы, что сами проверяют коллекции на равенство.
15. Отсутствие тестов контроллеров. Вы уверены, что тестов для сервисов достаточно?
16. Readme - у вашего проекта нет названия, а его назначение стоит после списка технологий. Сначала назовите проект как то. Потом опишите что проект делает. Потом его назначение (например, создан как пример работы с платформой MVC чтобы прокачать скиллы), потом уже пишите про технологии и как проект запустить.

В общем, проект неплохо выглядит для начинающего. Складывается впечатление, что вы много ещё не знаете и опыта у вас нет в разработке совсем. Для начинающего - это норма. Если вы себя позиционируете как мидл разработчика или выше - то у вас серьезные пробелы.

**Ответы на ваши вопросы**

> Верна ли в принципе построенная мною архитектура?

Верной арзитектуры нет в природе. Есть архитектура, что решает вашу задачу. Вы используете типичную многослойную архитектуру. Что вы деаете не так в ней я выше уже написал

> Стоит ли нагромождать условиями и проверками service слой?

Нет, не стоит. Если параметр будет передан как null - код должен упасть при попытке вызова метода этого параметра.

> нормальной ли практикой будет просто регистрировать службу ProductService

В pet проекте, которые априори небольшой, нормально регистрировать классы. В больших проектах как это делается - [читайте про букву D из SOLID](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/905310/179763)

> Следует ли разбивать класс миграций на несколько или можно создавать все нужные таблицы в одном?

Если я верно помню (я на дотнете уже года 2 не пишу), то каждая миграция накатывается со своей транзакцией. Вот и думайте, как вам надо, чтобы ваша БД либо вся накатилась или вся не накатилась, либо использовать кучу миграций и иметь полу-накатаную БД. С точки зрения орагнизации кода разницы никакой абсолютно. Со смысловой точки каждая миграция - это законченный функционал. Если вы накатили миграции, но последняя не накатилась и ваш проект не может запуститься, ваша БД останется в неконсистентном состоянии.

Comment: Понравился ответ от tym32167, пока что не могу оставлять комментарии, поэтому напишу здесь, подробный разбор создания интернет-магазина ASP.NET Core MVC на .NET 5 [вот здесь](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLePGPxR0FDm_HvURobtaz8GrLaI-iQhhc), включая разбор понятий View, ViewModels, ViewBag, паттерн Репозиторий, Entity Framewurk и аннотация для баз данных, сервер идентификации и т.д.

Comment: Это мой первый проект на asp.net, просто хотелось сразу вливаться в разработку с чистым кодом, вот и спросил про моменты, где сомневался.

Спасибо Вам огромное! Пойду читать статьи о каждом замечании и переделывать проект. Ещё раз спасибо большое, удачи в разработке!

Comment: Пожалуйста. Если помогло - галочка слева от ответа :)