# Сделайте код-ревью. С#

Tags: c#, .net, инспекция-кода

очень бы хотелось получить код-ревью, программа для создания и прохождения викторин.
Ссылка на репозиторий: https://github.com/juliion/Quiz

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: так а что там смотреть то? У вас какой то архитектурный подход там использован? Вы что то из ООП/SOLID там сделали? В какую сторону дедать код ревью?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Просили фидбек, вот вам фидбек

1. *manager классы - не хорошо, не понятно, что они менеджат и почему они менеджеры. Может переименовать в Сервисы?
2. DataManager - типа сохраняет и загружает все данные, но почему то при этом другие *Менеджеры знают о том, как сохраняются данные и даже указывают пути к файлам. То есть, если завтра надо будет хранить не в файлах, а в БД, надо переделывать все менеджеры. Это не есть хорошо.
   Как делать хорошо?

- сделать классы/интерфейсы для хранения сущностей
- прокинуть эти классы как параметры конструкторов ваших менеджеров
- менеджеры только вызывают методы, они не настраивают способ хранения
- способ хранения определяется в корне композиции или отдельным классом настроек

3. Статические классы - зло. Вы гвоздями классы прибиваете друг дружке. Вы даже нормально протестировать не сможете статические классы и классы, где используются статические классы.
4. Где тесты? Юнит тесты хотя бы?
5. Почитайте про [DI/IoC](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/905310/179763), у вас просто лапша классов, если захочется что то поменять в вашем коде, я подозреваю, придется половину проекта переписывать
6. Ни проверки ошибок, ни проверки, что вообще что то разумное ввел юзер, даже сам метод назван непонятно. Такой метод не должен существовать публично и уж явно не должен быть статическим.

   ```
    public static int GetChoice()
    {
        Console.Write("\n>  Выберите нужное действие: ");
        int choice;
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out choice);
        return choice;
    }
   ```
7. У вас все просто зависит от консоли. То есть, если я веб-сервис захочу написать или ещё какой другой способ общения с юзером, я так понимаю, мне надо будет весь ваш код выкинуть и переписывать заново
8. Ваш класс Меню не является меню, а просто набор методов для отрисовки чего то в консоли. Тогда уж что то типа ConsoleMenuRenderer хотя бы, хотя имхо такой класс существовать не должен.
9. Ваши модели не расширяемы. Ну вот например, если мне надо будет сделать вопрос, где надо упорядочить ответы? Или вопрос, где ответ в свободной форме должен быть записан? Или ещё что - я ток понимаю, придется выкинуть ваши модели вместе со всеми сохраненными файлами
10. Вы зачем то данные хардкодите в коде. Вот зачем нужен QuizType? А если завтра я захочу добавить вопросы про программирование, мне надо код менять для этого?
11. `QuizModel.public int CountMax(Quiz quiz)` - если методы используются только внутри моделей, они должны быть приватными.
12. `namespace QuizModel` имейте какое то правило именования неймспейсов. Например `MyCompany.MyProject.MyDomain.MySomething` ну как пример `Juliion.QuizGame.Models`
13. Ппочему то проверку на существование юзера делает класс `Scores`. Почитайте про S из SOLID
14. `public class Users : List<User>` у вас коллекции элементов ещё и выполняют бизнес логику. Вы сами не путаетесь? Почитайте про S из SOLID
15. Названия типа `Creator`, `Editor`, `Manager` - вообще не говорят о том, что эти классы делают. Давайте им осмысланные имена.

В общем, вердикт такой. Для начинающего, совсем начинающего, это неплохо. Что надо подучить: ОПП, паттерны, SOLID, разделение обязанностей, какие то архитектурные паттерны (mvc хотя бы), как писать классы для расширяемости, основы инверсии управления, обязательно хотя бы азы юнит тестирования, ну и побольше практики.

Книги почитать: Мартин Фаулер - Шаблоны корпоративных приложений, Боб Мартин - его трилогия про читый код, чистую архитектуру и идеального программиста. Это просто для начала.

Если вы претендуете хотя бы на джуниора, то рекомендации становятся более критичными.

Если вы позиционируете себя как программиста с опытом, то я в это не поверю =)

Comment: Читал, как роман. На всякий случай, я не автор вопроса, просто сочувствующий. Спасибо большое, tym32167! (причем, спасибо - не в первый раз)

Comment: На вяский случай: про SOLID читать полезно, и есть много довольно понятных видео на ютьюбе. Но я помню еще те времена, когда я сам не понимал, зачем нужны все эти сложности. Пока не встретился с действительно сложным проектом, в котором без разделения слоёв абстракций и тестов было бы невозможно разобраться. Поэтому, хорошо бы сначала понять, зачем :-) я навскидку нашел такое учебнео видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rz4S0v7K7Ho&ab_channel=BadooTech Ну, и хорошо бы разобраться, что такое стабы, фейки и моки. Будут вопросы - пишите еще!

Comment: @ЮляИонова если помогло, там есть галочка слева от ответа

Comment: @S.H. Для юнит тестов есть хорошая книга роя ошерова- art of unit testing

Comment: @tym32167 - Да, и, кажется, именно Вы мен её в прошлый раз посоветовали. Теперь вот наслаждаюсь полученным знанием :-)