# Не могу разобраться с сервисами, DI, Inversion of Control (IoC)

Tags: c#, .net-6

Здравствуйте объясните пожалуйста простыми словами что такое "сервисы", "Dependency Injection" , IoC container. А так же время жизни сервисов "Transient, Scoped, Singleton" в .NET 6.
Читал статью на Метаните, но так и не разобрался.

Comment: В данном [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1278817/220553) я отвечал на ряд вопросов, почитайте, думаю поймете, начиная с `Что такое сервис`.

Comment: [Как правильно сделать dependency injection](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/905310/179763)?